# Deleting/Removing Group in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I seem to be having a very odd problem with my iPhone project in XCode4.

By accident, I seem to have dragged a new group I created out of my main project group:

[image: Problem]

When I try to move the group back into the project group, XCode crashes. When I try to delete the group by dragging it to the trash can, no such luck either. Is this because it's an iPhone project, and I somehow have messed up the entire directory of groups?

Comment: This sounds like a XCode4 bug (it is still in preview). You should file a report with Apple. Have you tried opening the file up in XCode 3.x and seeing if you can fix it? The project files should be backwards-compatible.

Comment: When I open the project in XCode 3, the folder doesn't appear... but when I open it in 4, there it is again! :(

Comment: Xcode 4 is *still* under NDA.

Comment: I just realized, "Delete Group" doesn't even show up on the right click menu for any of the groups... am I using the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved- I hit the delete button with the group selected, and clicked "Continue" when presented with the error dialogue, which ended up removing the group.

Comment: Any details?  I having a similar problem.  When you say delete button, do you mean on your keyboard, or somewhere in the XCode UI?

Comment: I mean on my keyboard- deleting the group.

Comment: Why did someone just downvote my answer to my question from eight months ago? I found a solution, and posted how I did it. It's not my responsibility to check answers from over a month after I asked the question to see if there are better answers.

Comment: @element119 you answer isn't correct. with your """solution""" you deleted all the Runner.xcodeproj

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. 
I had this empty group or folder whatever it is (let's call it "stubborn group") at the same level than my project. I wasn't able to delete it since the option was disable when I right clicked on it.

This is how you can remove the "stubborn group"

1. Right click on your project and select "New Group from Selection"
   This will create a new group named "New Group" and put your project in it
2. Now drag your project outside of "New Group" to the top (not inside) of the "Stubborn group"
3. Next is to highlight both groups and "Delete"

Answer (score 2):

Not even the "delete button on my keyboard" was working for me. I edited the ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata file to remove the Group
 element. Xcode4 noticed that the file was changed by another application, asked if I wanted to keep the change, and closed the project. I re-opened the project and the group was gone.