# Xcode: Delete extern folder

Tags: xcode4

I have this distribution:

[image]

I want delete new group folder, but its impossible!!!!

I cant add new files inside my project, for default only can add in this new folder....

[image]

If i drag my proyect to other folder, the result is:

[image]

i cant delete this folder...

If you try drag this folder inside the proyect:

[image]

Comment: ok take a look at this [post][1]
 i hope this will make a sense 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907059/deleting-removing-group-in-xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just *drag* your project outside your new group folder then right click it > *Delete*.

Comment: if you can drag this folder to be one of the project group folders then try to delete it again
not sure if  that will work!

Comment: Its impossible delete this, funny but inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

select your offending group in the list of files & folders & groups (to select it)

then hold down the control key and click again (which brings up the contextual menu)

choose the "Delete" option

Comment: I see in your edit that "Delete" isn't enabled.  What happens when you close your project and restart Xcode?  Does "Delete" enable in that case?

Comment: No, its impossible delete this.

Comment: The problem is that my proyect ejecute correctly, but if i want add some files its impossible inside this, for default add files in this folder and i have to drag and duplicate this new files in my proyect...